# Get all craft.embeddedAssets

Tags: plugin-embeddedassets

I'm new to using craft cms and have been using this site to answer several questions. I decided I should give back. I have been using the Embedded Assets plugin but could not figure out the "for loop" code in a Matrix field to display links to all selected YouTube videos.

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify. It looks like your code example above is correct. If you want to contribute an answer, can you move the answer to the field below and rephrase your question as someone else might ask (e.g. How do I...)? See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Thank you. This is my first Question/Answer on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one part of a bigger switch case statement for a Craft Matrix field.

- My block is called **newFeatureVideo**.
- my field is called **video**.

```
{% case "newFeatureVideo" %}
  {% for items in block.video.all() %}
    {% set item = craft.embeddedAssets.get(items) %}
    <li><a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
```